# Is there a way to dynamically create a model at runtime based on a specific table that is chosen by a user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model-view-controller

I am trying to write a web application that allows a user to choose a specific table from a list of options, and then allow them to view and edit said table. The web app works fine when I hard code a model for one table. Is there a way that, based on which table the user chooses, I can dynamically create a model and view. All the tables are different sizes, have different data types, etc. Any direction would be incredibly appreciated.

Comment: no, you can't dynamically create C# code on the fly at runtime. How many tables are involved? Is it practical to pre-create models and views for all of them? If not, then you'll have to come up with a generic TableEditor model which can store all the columns in the chosen table and the data types etc, and then have a view which builds the editor form dynamically based on that information. When the user posts its back you'll have to dynamically validate the input somehow, and come up with some rules about what makes a valid submission. Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for the input. There are way too many tables involved to practically pre-create models and views for all of them. I'll look into making a generic model.